# Why does my code think a value is Microsoft.IdentityModel.Json.Linq.JObject when it is actually supposed to be Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject?

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I am having a lot of difficulty with a failing unit test. Specifically,

`JwtRequestAuthorizeTests.authorize_should_accept_complex_objects_in_request_object()`

The test attempts to add an Object parameter to the Claims array, and it is failing because after the request goes through the pipeline, an expected parameter called "someObj" is missing.

For the record, `someObj` is simply a json object defined as:

```
{{
    "foo": {
        "bar": "bar"
    },
    "baz": "baz"
}}
```

Also for the record, when I pull the latest IdentityServer code from GitHub the test passes.

I've discovered that the reason it's failing is because in the method `JwtRequestValidator.ProcessPayloadAsync(JwtSecurityToken token)`, the variable `value` is of a type different than what's expected. Specifically, the code thinks it's `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Json.Linq.JObject` when it should be `Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject`. I can't for the life of me figure out how or why this is the case.

I've included this image to show you that I'm not crazy (or at least, why I don't think I'm crazy). You can see that the cast from `value` to `JObject` fails, as `jobj = null`, and you can also see that `value.GetType()` returns `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Json.Linq.JObject`.

[image]

**So can StackOverflow please tell me why this is happening, and perhaps how I can fix it?**

Also, I think it's worth noting that I'm referencing Newtonsoft.Json as it should be:

[image]

Comment: I ran into this exact issue too today, were you able to resolve it?

Comment: no, sorry dude. it's too long ago, I can't remember.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After migrating from .Netframework WebAPI to dotnetcore3.1, I ran into the exact same issue. I can't believe I searched all over the internet, and was only able to find this question as the only related result.

Apparently JWT payload type is no longer `NewtonSoft.Json.Linq.JObject`. It is `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Json.Linq.JObject` now and is inaccessible outside of its namespace.

My guess is Microsoft has changed the definition and didn't expect people to use the type outside of its namespace.

What I ended up doing is getting rid of the type check, and just parse directly in a `try{} catch{}` block.
[image: parse-payload-directly]

Hope this will help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft decided to port in a copy of JSON.NET so that it can maintain a chain of trust. You can find where it's defined: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/pull/1251

Answer (score 0):

I was in a similar situation. I did as chy600 said and used JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to fix it.

Before:

```
((JObject)jwtPayload["field_1"])["field_2"]?.ToString()?.ToUpper() ?? ""
```

After:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JwtPayload>(jwtPayload["field_1"].ToString())["field_2"]?.ToString()?.ToUpper() ?? ""
```